# how do sizing image with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to use avatar through paperclip. in tutorial use gravatar

messages_helper.rb

```
 def recipients_options(chosen_recipient = nil)
 s = ''
 User.all.each do |user|
 s << "<option value='#{user.id}' 
               data-img-src='#{gravatar_image_url(user.email, size: 50)}' 
               #{'selected' if user == chosen_recipient}>
               #{user.name}</option>"
 end
 s.html_safe
 end
```

i change on this code and it working.

```
module MessagesHelper
  def recipients_options(chosen_recipient = nil)
   s = ''
   User.all.each do |user|
    s << "<option value='#{user.id}' data-img-src='#{user.avatar.url(:thumb)}'  
               #{'selected' if user == chosen_recipient}>#{user.username}</option>"
   end
   s.html_safe
  end


end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
  <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it ' %>
</div>
```

user.rb

```
 has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "150x150>", :thumb => "30x30#" }, default_url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myinstick/logo/instagram-icon.png"
 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

But! if user dont have avatar, that use image paperclip default. and it does not scaling  and It looks big. how to set the style or size.

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGNVG.png)

Comment: Just find the properly css selector for this image and create a css with something like: `.my-big-img-class { max-width: 50px }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Drop-down list uses 
jquery.image-select.js

```
(function($) {

// Image template, this can be overridden from the constructor (options.template),
// must contains {src} placeholder. Ther eare two class names 'chose-image' or 'chose-image-small', modifiy in CSS
var fn_template = '<img class="{class_name} " src="{url}" />';

// Store the original 'chosen' method
var fn_chosen = $.fn.chosen;........
```

I can set class for all images, like this

```
 var fn_template = '<img class="{class_name} image-circle-minisize" src="{url}" />';
```

and everything works

Answer (score 1):

in your model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
        :styles => { thumb: "100x100#", medium: "300x300#", large: "900x500#"}
```

or whatever size you want it to be. The `#` is for cropping. It will select the center of the image and crop the specified height and width from there. You can also just use the default `>` if you don't want the cropping... and in your view:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem lies elsewhere. if image uploaded - then all is well. but if image missing,  then loaded the standard " default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png'" . and it looks large. Problem here: data-img-src='#{user.avatar.url(:thumb)}' . if i use code like this :  "data-img-src='#{user.avatar.url(:thumb), size: 50}'" . code not working.